# Why do apps require a certain minimum Android version?

Tags: android-versions, compatibility

All android apps require a specific Android version. Why is that so? Can't we use any ICS app on GB? For example, touch-to-focus is a very simple feature – but it wants Android 4. What can I do to use it on GB? Or *Wolfram alpha*, which is a browser-like app. Why does it require at least ICS?

Comment: Your question is really too broad for us to answer here. As for the Android version needed, that's set by the developer of each app. You'd have to ask them _why_ they require a specific version or not. The [Wikipedia article on Android version history](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Android_version_history) has more information on what is changed between versions than anyone would probably want to know.

Answer (score 3):

You can compare that to other OS's versions as well: A program designed for e.g. Windows 8 does not necessarily run on Windows 95. Development goes on, and that includes the [API](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Api)s they provide. With each new version, new interfaces are available to the programmers, saving them from "re-inventing the wheel": Why code an entire library yourself, when it's much easier to access one that's already available? But if a specific feature was introduced with version 4.1, and the developer made use of that in his app, that app would not work properly on versions 4.0 and below, obviously.

So depending on the APIs used, such an app might not even start on a lower version, or some core functionality would not be available at all or even crash. To prevent the user from such mishap, developers must declare a "minimum required API level" in the Manifest<sup>1</sup> of their apps. As each "API level" corresponds with a specific Android version, this makes the app "incompatible" with lower versions.

---

<sup>1</sup> The [Manifest](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/manifest-intro.html) is an XML file included in every Android app, declaring the app's requirements.